# Distribution of static friction forces between two opposite surfaces

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, friction

Please, could you help me with this question. It seems very easy but I struggle to find info on the web, and the chatGPT gives an apparently wrong answer.
I have the following static setup, where the applied external force is obviously lower than either maximum static friction force (the one between the block A and block B, and the one between the block A and ground). The sum of these two friction forces on the block A must equal (with the opposite sign) the external force of 2 Newtons applied to the block A. I can't figure out whether these two friction forces should be equal (1 Newton each) or be proportional to the respective normal forces or whatever other quantity.

[image: My static friction case]

Comment: The horizontal acceleration of block B is zero, so the net horizontal force on B must be zero. The only force acting on B is $F_{ab}$ so $F_{ab}$ must be zero. Then you can apply the same reasoning for block A.

Comment: Thank you so much. It appears then that block A should start exerting any force on block B only after block A's external force exceeds the maximum static friction force from the ground. Very interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thank @JohnRennie for the answer in the comment section above. It appears that since the block B's acceleration is still zero and the only horizontal force acting upon it is F<sub>A,B</sub>, the latter should be equal to zero, too. Thus F<sub>B,A</sub> is zero, and F<sub>G,A</sub> = −F<sub>E</sub> = −2 N.

My afterthought: if we don't abstract ourselves from the nature of the underlying surface and assume it belongs to an Earth-like (but resting) object, we may come up with the following distribution of static friction forces and establish that the friction force exerted upon block A is being split between the lower and upper surfaces in proportion to the masses of the neighbouring objects (after subtracting block A's mass).

[image]